# How to position an element relative to the screen (viewport)?

Tags: php, jquery, css

So, I have a button that is located at the bottom right corner of a page as shown in the picture ("current"):

[image]

The set up is pretty simple:

```
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<div class="button" style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0px;">
    Button
</div>
```

Now, is there a way to locate the button at the bottom of "visible" screen and not necessary at the bottom of the content as shown on "need" picture?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `position: fixed`.

```
#myDiv
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qp2x6awx/)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `position: fixed` to attach it to the bottom right of the viewport.

```
selector {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

---

> [**`position: fixed`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning)
>
> Fixed positioning is similar to absolute positioning, with the
>   exception that the element's containing block is the viewport. This is
>   often used to create a floating element that stays in the same
>   position even after scrolling the page.